# Project is growing ang growing, Xcode slowing down

Tags: xcode, project

My projects is growing. It includes about 16 thousands .m4a (sound) files, because it's the App helping to learn languages with examples, but only few classes and files containing code.

Since I 've added those 16000 files working on this project is PITA. Renaming any file takes time, compiling, building, launching the app takes so much time. Of course I know that about 200MB has to be transfered, but the problem is the compouter is responding badly at that time.

Fortnately I have a SSD drive and 8GB RAM, I don't want to even think, how long would it take on HDD.

Is there any way to improve the perfomance?

I'll be also responsible for creating more than a ten similar apps for other pair of languages, and I would like to have all of them in one project and only play with targets. So if I don't do anything with performance now, there is high probability than one day I'll throw away this computer through the window of my house on the 2nd floor...

Comment: File a bug;  this is an Xcode performance issue.   A better solution than SQLite would *have been* to use either a ZIP file [designed for this] or Core Data [basically no code required].  But, since you got it working... enjoy until you run into a performance issue or feature that can't be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, by creating an additional Core Data sqlite file, that contains all of the resources, so the entity looks like:

name (nsstring) - name of file
data (nsdata) - binary of file

works like a charm. Quick builds, quick debugs, just like before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading each m4a from the web once you need it. means - the app will be thin when a user download it, but once a sound file have to be played - it'll be downloaded from the web and saved on the SD. next time you have to play this file - play it from the SD.

And yeah, XCode have many problems - this is one of them..

Comment: The problem is the application has to work offline and even though server and transfer cost.

Comment: anyway you gonna have server costs.. because the m4a files will be downloaded to the device anyway, with the app or later on..

Comment: no I won't. It's an iPhone Application and I don't care about Apple servers. :).